# Postback with HTML Editor Extender on page causes JavaScript error in IE11

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, ajax

I have added an HTML Editor Extender to the page I'm working on and now ANYTIME I cause a post back on the page I get the following Javascript error:

> JavaScript runtime error: Invalid argument.

And nothing happens after that. This works fine in IE10 or below and all other browsers that I'm aware of, however it does not work in IE11 which I need it to work in. Does anyone know of any fixes for this issue?

Comment: would you post that line?

Comment: This is the line that is erroring in the ajax toolkit:
b.collapse(this._editableDiv.firstChild,c);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like it's a known issue with the AjaxToolKit.
Try inserting this below the head tag:

`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10,chrome=1" />`

Comment: I Have marked this as the correct answer, after some research I have found that it is a known problem with the ajax toolkit and wont be fixed until the next release so I have used this to open the browser in IE10 mode, not ideal but seems the only option right now, thanks